# How to locate file and based on the content to append a new lines?

Tags: powershell

I try unsuccessfully to run the next script:

1.try to find all .properties files under D:\
if the file content include 'iis' then to append a two separate lines to the 
file.

and

2.try to find all .prop2 files under c:\
if the file content include'win88' append a two separate lines to the file.

Script:

```
$file1 = Get-ChildItem -Path D:\* -Filter *.properties -Recurse 
$file2 = GetChildItem -Path C:\* -Filter *.prop2 -Recurse
if ( $file1 -contains '*iis*') {Add-Content $file1 "'nServer1'nServer2"};
 if ( $file2 -contains '*win88*') {Add-Content $file2 "'nServer3'nServer4"};
```

Answer (score 0):

`Get-ChildItem` can return multiple files.  You need to loop through the list of files, get their contents, then check if they contain the string you are looking for.  Here's a simple solution for `*.properties`.

```
$file1 = Get-ChildItem -Path D:\* -Filter *.properties -Recurse | % {
    $fileContents = Get-Content $_
    if ( $fileContents -contains '*iis*') {Add-Content $file1 "'nServer1'nServer2"};
}
```